# php generate sequence based on array value

Tags: php, arrays, sequence

I want this array

```
$passengers = array(
            'adult' => 2,
            'child' => 1,
            'infant' => 1
        );
```

to change like this. Create a sequence based on number of persons.

```
Array(
[adult] => Array(
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
    )

[child] => Array(
        [0] => 3
    )

[infant] => Array(
        [0] => 4
    )
```

)

I'm stuck with this code

```
        $seq=1;
        foreach($passengers as $paxKey => $paxVal){

            if($paxVal>1){
                $pax[$paxKey][] = $seq;
                $seq = $seq+$paxVal;
            }else{
                $seq=$paxVal+$seq;
                $pax[$paxKey][] = $seq;
            }
        }
```

Any assistance is highly appreciated.

Comment: What you want to create exactly ? can you provide details correctly ? From above array to below array or from below array to above ?

Comment: And where are you stuck? I highly doubt that this array conversion is useful at all. But this should be solveable all by your self. Hint: for-loop ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$pax = [];
$seq = 1;

foreach($passengers as $key => $val){
  while($val--) {
   $pax[$key][] = $seq;
   $seq++;
 }
}
```

There are two cycles: the first one cycles the passengers, the second one creates as many elements as you need for each (kind of?) passenger.

Comment: What is the use of `$pax`?

Comment: my fault, copy/paste error. now it should be correct :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = [];
$counter = 1;
foreach($passengers as $key=>$value)
{
  for($i=0;$i<$value;$i++)
  {
      $result[$key][] = $counter;
      $counter++;
  }   
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.